# Why does codacy give `Unnecessary block` error for function declaration?

Tags: static-analysis, pmd, codacy

We are using codacy for static code analysis. On pushing a change to the js file, where we are declaring a function that returns an object, it is giving the below error.

[image: screenshot of the codacy issue]

Internally, codacy tells us this is reported since PMD 5.0. We are not sure if this is an actual issue in the code or in the analyzer. If it is a code issue then what is the correct way to solve this?

EDIT:
Using PMD version 6.48.0

Answer (score 1):

This issue is Open with PMD here.
https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues/4129

There are workarounds mentioned. For the codacy side we need to disable the rule until it is fixed